# How to pass the check empty string with enum in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How I can ignore the error like `validation failed: gender: "" is not a valid enum value for path gender` when receive a empty value to save into database

My schema look like:

```
Person {
  gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['men', 'women'],
    required: false
  }
}
```

In my code (NodeJS)

I have a check:

```
if (body.gender && !['men', 'women'].includes(body.gender.toLowercase())) {
  throw Error("Gender invalid");
}

await savePerson(body);
```

If have to lowerCase value to check in case insensitive

I think in Javascript empty string is not same with null or undefined, so the error is not throw. I don't want to check !isNullOrUndefined(body.gender) as well. But in process save to mongo, error `validation failed: gender: "" is not a valid enum value for path gender` has been threw by mongoose

Comment: `if (body.gender === "") delete body.gender;` get rid if it ;)

Comment: enum accepts null, so instead of '' you can alternatively set it as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first condition in your `if` is true when `body.gender` is not null or undefined or empty string "". So these values pass your validation and go to the `.save()` function

You can change to this, it will catch the invalid values above :

```
if (!['men', 'women'].includes(body.gender)) {
  throw Error("Gender invalid");
}
```

```js
console.log(!['men', 'women'].includes(undefined)); // true
console.log(!['men', 'women'].includes(null)); // true
console.log(!['men', 'women'].includes("")); // true
```

---

**Edit**: So, the condition is "the gender is string and is one of "men", "women" case insensitive". I suggest this validation:

```
 if (typeof(body.gender) !== "string" || !['men', 'women'].includes(body.gender.toLowerCase())) {
  throw Error("Gender invalid");
}
```

Below I run some test:

```js
function isValidGender(gender) {

  if (typeof(gender) !== "string" || !['men', 'women'].includes(gender.toLowerCase())) {
     console.log("Error");
  } else {
     console.log("Valid");
  }
}
isValidGender(undefined);
isValidGender(null);
isValidGender("");
isValidGender("Men");
isValidGender("wOmEn");
isValidGender("AA");
```

Comment: That good idea, but I always lowercase value before check that includes or not. It my mistake on question. Let me update describe

Comment: I got it, but It still be an issue if have a lot of field need to check, but I think we don't have another way